# Show list items in a stateful widget linked to the item

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of integers. Each of this item is displayed in a statefull widget by iterating the list in the build method.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:widget_list/ItemWidget.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Item list state demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Item list state demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static int itemsCount = 0;

  final List<int> _items = List.empty(growable: true);

  void _add() {
    setState(() {
      _items.add(itemsCount++);
    });
  }

  void _remove() {
    setState(() {
      _items.removeAt(0);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => _add(),
                  child: const Text('Add item'),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => _items.isNotEmpty ? _remove() : null,
                  child: const Text('Remove item'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            for (var item in _items) ItemWidget(item: item),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Each of this widget, has a statically incremented integer "id" in it's state. Both the item and the widget id are displayed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

var widgetCount = 0;

class ItemWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int item;

  const ItemWidget({
    required this.item,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ItemWidget> createState() => _ItemWidgetState();
}

class _ItemWidgetState extends State<ItemWidget> {
  final int widgetId = widgetCount++;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Item ${widget.item} / Widget $widgetId");
    return Text("Item ${widget.item} / Widget $widgetId");
  }
}
```

When I add an item in the list, it is displayed in a newly generated widget. E.g. first item 0 is displayed in widget 0.

[image]

But if I remove an item at the beginning of the list (e.g. item 0), it's not the first widget that is destoyed, but the last one. The item 1 is then displayed in widget 0.

[image]

The widget item is final, so it cannot change. The widget ids are still the same, so the states were not rebuild. Then, why are the states no more consistent with the widgets?

This is done in FLutter desktop for Linux, v3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to performance optimization, the Flutter rendering process allows the widgets to be "reused" if the objects assigned to their properties have the same type.

If you don't want this to happen, you must define the Key property on the widget. You'll find a complete video explanation on https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html.

In the example provided, the `item` property of `ItemWidget` is final, so it looks like Flutter is violating this concept. However, it's not directly the `Widget` class that is shown, but an underlying `Element`: "an instantiation of a Widget at a particular location in the tree". So it may appear that the `item` property was changed, but it's just that the underlying `Element` was not updated property.

Answer (score 0):

In the itemWidget you are creating a value from 0 so for each element that is rendered it will start from 0. please check the code below

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Item list state demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Item list state demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static int itemsCount = 0;

  final List<ItemInfo> _items = List.empty(growable: true);

  void _add() {
    setState(() {
      itemsCount++;
      _items.add(ItemInfo(itemsCount, itemsCount));
    });
  }

  void _remove() {
    setState(() {
      _items.removeAt(0);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => _add(),
                  child: const Text('Add item'),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => _items.isNotEmpty ? _remove() : null,
                  child: const Text('Remove item'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            for (var item in _items) ItemWidget(item: item),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and Itemwidget to be like this

```
class ItemWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final ItemInfo item;

  const ItemWidget({
    required this.item,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ItemWidget> createState() => _ItemWidgetState();
}

class _ItemWidgetState extends State<ItemWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
        "Item ${widget.item.itemVal} / Widget ${widget.item.itemIndex}");
  }
}
```

also I created a class named ItemInfo which will hold both the value and its index.

```
class ItemInfo {
  int itemVal;
  int itemIndex;
  ItemInfo(this.itemVal, this.itemIndex);
}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You removed the state property, so it doesn't answer the question, it just removes it.

Comment: Yes it is removing that element, If you set the counter inside the item widget it will always start from 0

Comment: Yes, I this always start from 0 after application startup. As it's static, it will then increment for each widget, as proven by the demo. This is how I want it to work. The issue is not related to initialization, but to state consistency with the widget after a new rendering when the parent list is modified.

Comment: but when you rebuild the widget it will set to 0. so that was causing the issue.

Comment: Why would it be set to 0 ? It's final, so it cannot change. If the state is rebuilt, it would take the next increment, not 0.

Comment: Please add a print statement just below the static variable and you can see it setting to 0 everytime you rebuild it

Comment: I've replaced the static property by a global variable. The problem is still there.

Comment: Do you want it to start from 0 or have the value that its assigned with?

Comment: I want the widget state to stay the same for a given widget. This means that if a widget receives 1 as an attribute and has 1 in its state, it should never change until explicitely done.

Comment: Yeah so in the example that is posted the list is filled with objects which will save both state and its value.